# TypeError: schema[parameter].validateAsync when running API call?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, joi

When I call any route in my express server , I am getting this error

```
TypeError: schema[parameter].validateAsync is not a function

    at validate (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express-validation/lib/index.js:18:55)
    at /home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express-validation/lib/index.js:26:25
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express-validation/lib/index.js:26:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at cors (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
    at /home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:224:17
    at originCallback (/home/techrova/Videos/VideoStream/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:214:15)
```

I cannot understand what happening ?

Please explain me ?

Even I can't add details to this question , since I have no clue !!

I cant find out where this error occurs since the error message not showing the exact location and the function `validateAsync` not found in the code

package.json

```
{
  "name": "videostream",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": false,
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.8.0",
    "npm": ">=2.15.11",
    "yarn": ">=0.20.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "npm-run-all clean transpile",
    "clean": "rimraf dist-server",
    "watch:dev": "nodemon",
    "server": "node ./dist-server/index.js",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development npm-run-all build server",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production npm-run-all build server",
    "transpile": "babel . --ignore node_modules,test --out-dir dist-server --copy-files --source-maps --include-dotfiles"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "express",
    "node",
    "node.js",
    "mongodb",
    "mongoose",
    "es6",
    "mocha",
    "istanbul",
    "REST",
    "API",
    "boilerplate"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "3.2.0",
    "bcrypt": "5.0.0",
    "bluebird": "3.7.2",
    "body-parser": "1.19.0",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.5",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "debug": "^4.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "express-busboy": "8.0.0",
    "express-jwt": "6.0.0",
    "express-validation": "3.0.5",
    "express-winston": "4.0.5",
    "fcm-push": "1.1.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.0.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "helmet": "4.0.0",
    "html-pdf": "^2.2.0",
    "http-status": "^1.4.2",
    "joi": "17.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.5.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.19",
    "mailgun-js": "0.22.0",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "2.27.0",
    "mongoose": "5.9.27",
    "mongoose-delete": "0.5.2",
    "mongoose-paginate": "5.0.3",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.3",
    "morgan": "1.10.0",
    "natives": "^1.1.6",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.2",
    "nodejs-base64": "^1.0.3",
    "nodemailer": "6.4.11",
    "nodemailer-mailgun-transport": "2.0.0",
    "nodemailer-sendgrid-transport": "^0.2.0",
    "nodemailer-sendinblue-transport": "1.2.3",
    "otp-generator": "1.1.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "stripe": "8.84.0",
    "twilio": "^3.48.2",
    "winston": "3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "1.0.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.24.1",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "commitizen": "^4.1.2",
    "coveralls": "^3.1.0",
    "cross-env": "7.0.2",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "3.2.0",
    "del": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "14.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.0",
    "eslint-watch": "7.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-babel": "8.0.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-newer": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.5.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "istanbul": "1.1.0-alpha.1",
    "mocha": "8.1.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.1",
    "supertest": "4.0.2",
    "supertest-as-promised": "4.0.2",
    "validate-commit-msg": "^2.14.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "commitizen": {
      "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
    }
  },
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "exec": "npm run dev",
    "watch": [
      "server/*",
      "config/*",
      "index.js",
      ".env"
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "**/__tests__/**",
      "*.test.js",
      "*.spec.js"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "add-module-exports"
    ]
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import util from 'util';
import fs from 'fs';

import config from './config/config';
import app from './config/express';
import socketService from './server/services/socket.service';
import Stripe from './server/services/stripe';

import debuger from 'debug';
const debug = new debuger('videostream:index');
import Promise from 'bluebird';

mongoose.Promise = Promise;

const mongoUri = config.mongo.host;
mongoose.connect(mongoUri, { useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true, keepAlive: true });
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
  console.info('The MongoDB connected successfully');
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', () => {
  throw new Error(`unable to connect to database: ${mongoUri}`);
});

if (config.MONGOOSE_DEBUG) {
  mongoose.set('debug', (collectionName, method, query, doc) => {
    debug(`${collectionName}.${method}`, util.inspect(query, false, 20), doc);
  });
}
//
import * as serverer from 'http';

const server = serverer.createServer(app);
//if (!module.parent) {
  server.listen(config.port, () => {
    console.info(`Your server started on port ${config.port} (${config.env})`);
    const charge = { amount: '20', source: 'tok_1EOysZBDFs3Ptf0GdjyTYMN0' };

        socketService.startSocket();
  });
//}


export default server;
```

Please help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your validators on routes. Error comes from express-validation. Please see https://github.com/AndrewKeig/express-validation/issues/122